# Automated postcode searching on QGIS

Tags: qgis, postcode

I understand I need to use a plugin so I can search postcodes on QGIS.

Is there a tool which could take postcodes from a spreadsheet and search them in QGIS?

I would be searching a certain radius lets says 3km, is there something I could do which would show whether the postcodes is with in the radius or outside?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Batch Nominatim Geocoder](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisbatchnominatimgeocoder), available in QGIS core [since version 3.20](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-nominatim-geocoder-integration). I tested it with a few postcodes, together with the name of the country (like `8006,switzerland`), and it worked perfectly. Save your spreadsheet as csv, load it as layer in QGIS and use this layer as input to the geocoder.

It creates a point layer as output. If you need the very boundaries of the postcode zone, however, you must find actual polygon data or reconstruct the areas based on addresses ([see other solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/468697/88814)).

*Official layer with postcode zones (black) and point layer, based on Nominatim geocoded postcodes in red:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a query to retrieve all OpenStreetMap features that contain a `addr:postcode` tag, e.g. using [QuickOSM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/).
2. Aggregate the resulting layer(s) based on this tag to get one mulitpart feature per postcode.
3. Create a convex or concave hull around each mulitpart feature to approach the area the postcode covers.

---

Variant: insted of step 3, create voronoi polygons based on the centroids of each feature from step 2, then aggregate voronoi polygons based on the same postcode.

*Solution with the variant using voronoi polygons for a part of Zurich (Siwzterland): actual postcode dataset (red lines) and voronoi polygons, based on OSM addresses (black lines) - pretty good reconstruction for most areas:*

[image]